# QGIS sum up polygon features inside grid

Tags: qgis, vector-grid

I have a grid with population points inside each of the individual cells. I've used the "join attributes by location" tool to join each population point to their respective cell. Now I'd like to sum up all my population points inside each grid cell. I've used the field calculator using the following expression:

```
sum("id")
```

"id" being the id of each cell in the grid. But now, I have a sum of population for each row.
I'd just like to have one line with the cell id and the total population inside.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First you have to use a "spatial join" tool to join  called "join by location" to get "id" field from your grid to your points.

After you could use statistics tool to sum by 'ID'.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it, the statistics tool works for raster data, but not for a vector. The "show statistical summary" gives the stats for the whole vector. I need the sum of population per grid cell!

Comment: The name of the tool is "Statistics by category"